# How to I convert files above 200 kb in size to JSON schema on liquid XML?

Tags: liquid-xml

I'm trying to convert a very large JSON file to JSON Schema, but when I upload that file to Liquid_XML it gives me a prompt saying file size above 200 kb. Can buying a licensed version fix this issue? If so, which license to buy?

Answer (score 2):

The [online json converter tool](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-tools) has a 200kb limit, so you would need to use the desktop app [Liquid Studio](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-studio).

You would need a JSON Editor Edition license to use all of the JSON and JSON Schema tools.